# Changes in NBTExplorer do not change world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I really need help on teleporting my player while he is offline, as I accidentally added the `~` to `/tp @p ~ ~ ~300000000` and teleported to an illegal position. I then tried to use NBTExplorer to change the `Pos` data to normal, but when I load the world, the data resets like I didn't edit it at all. I tried copy, paste, and saving, but Minecraft keeps rejecting it!

What should I do?

Comment: Did you click the save button?

Answer (score 3):

In NBTExplorer make sure you are editing the level.dat file, not a playername.dat file as singleplayer worlds read from the level.dat, not one of the playername.dat files in the saves/savename/players/ folder.

Inside level.dat make sure you are editing `level.dat/Data/Player/Pos` and not `level.dat/Data/Spawn<X/Y/Z>`. When you are done make sure you hit the save button at the top to save it. As long as you overwrite these NBT tags and save the level.dat the game has nowhere else to look to find the player's position.

Comment: This is a thing that is hard to find.

Answer (score -3):

McEDIT your world and place your character back to spawn.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, but we need better answers than the really bad one-liner. Perhaps you could walk us through how to do it with MCEdit.